# Pivot table in SSRS (not tablix)

Tags: excel, reporting-services

Is it possible to output a dataset into tabular format in SSRS on sheet 1 for example, then set up pivot on sheet 2 on said dataset? I.e. I'm not looking for crosstab reports or drilldown reports using tablix, but rather when exported to excel I want it to be the actual Excel pivot function applied so that the user can start using the pivot functions rather than having to manually run pivot table on the dataset.

Comment: This isn't something you can do with SSRS. What you're looking for is PowerPivot which is an excel add-in from Microsoft that will let you hook into a source and slice, dice, & pivot the data.

Comment: How about having a separate file with the pivot table that refers to the data file that gets replaced daily with a new updated file?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you question correctly

you want to use same dataset to show data in table in `sheet1` when export to Excel

and `sheet2` show pivot table right ?

1. I think you should use 2 dataset one for table and one for pivot 
   (pivot = Complete data from SQL server)

then last question you want your report use pivot function in Excel (sending only detail data then use pivot on excel)

2. I think it's not possible when export data to excel it's fill complete value to cell